# My ajax request times out (or is really slow)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

My first forray into ajax webpages is causing me some problems.

My basic structure is that I have a table on a page, which I want to reload without refreshing the entire page.

So on clicking a button on the page it fires of this:

```
function RefreshMissionsAjax() {
  //fade out the old table.
  $(clientID('MissionsDisplay')).fadeOut(500);

  //request the new value from the page (calls the GetIncompleteMissions() method in the MissionViewer.aspx.cs page)
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "MissionViewer.aspx/GetIncompleteMissions",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (msg) {

      $(clientID('MissionsDisplay')).html(msg.d);
      $(clientID('MissionsDisplay')).fadeIn(500);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
        $(clientID('MissionsDisplay')).html('An error occured while trying to refresh the page data.');
        $(clientID('MissionsDisplay')).fadeIn(500);
    }
  });
}
```

And I have in the code bedind of an aspx page:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetIncompleteMissions()
{
    return GetHTMLTable();
}
```

This method just grabs some data, and creates a html table - nothing too fancy.

When the returned table is small (a dozen rows or less) then it works like a charm.
But when it gets larger, it takes a long long time.
At 100 rows it can take 5 minutes to render the table.
At 1000 rows I have left it for 30 minutes and nothing will happen after the fadeout.
(NB - it loads fairly quickly on the pageload, before the ajax refresh is used, so it is not the actual server side creation of the table thats the problem).

This is my first real attempt at doing something like this, so I dont know if this is the best way to do it - it was just something i pieced together that worked great when i was testing with small datasets.
Now, not so much.

Any ideas how I can make it usable?

Comment: Does it work quickly without the `fadeIn`?

Comment: 1000 rows!! You really need that much big table? It wont even be readable, try using pagination instead.

Comment: @dcodjer - 1000 rows is a relatively small table - its a table of data used primarily for reference, to quickly find what you need from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, use WCF instead, it should be lot faster.

Anyway, don't pass the raw HTML back, have the service return minimized data in JSON format then use this data in the onsuccess event to create the table on the fly with jQuery.

For example have the service return JSON array with 1000 items then iterate this array and add one row for each item.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this - see if it offers me much improvement.